# How to search only for schools in Swift LocationPicker Library

Tags: ios, swift, location, swift4

I am using this [library](https://github.com/almassapargali/LocationPicker) "Location Picker" for ios swift.
it basically search for places in the map, all kinds of places.

Can I restrict the search for only Schools? I need to search for schools ONLY

I am using swift4 and the latest xCode

Thank you very much

### IBAction function

```
@IBAction func pickASchool(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let locationPicker = LocationPickerViewController()

    let longitude :CLLocationDegrees = -122.0312186
    let latitude :CLLocationDegrees = 37.33233141

    let location = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude) //changed!!!
    print(location)

    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in
        print(location)

        if error != nil {
            print("Reverse geocoder failed with error" + (error?.localizedDescription)!)
            return
        }
        print("no error")
        if (placemarks?.count)! > 0 {

            print("in pm")

            let pm = placemarks![0]
            // you can optionally set initial location
            let initialLocation = Location(name: "My home", location: location, placemark: pm)
            locationPicker.location = initialLocation

            locationPicker.searchBarPlaceholder = "Search places" // default: "Search or enter an address"

            locationPicker.searchHistoryLabel = "Previously searched" // default: "Search History"

            // optional region distance to be used for creation region when user selects place from search results
            locationPicker.resultRegionDistance = 500 // default: 600

            locationPicker.completion = { location in
                // do some awesome stuff with location
            }

            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(locationPicker, animated: true)

            print(pm.locality!)
        }
        else {
            print("Problem with the data received from geocoder")
        }
    })



}
```

Comment: When you are getting response from server is there any key which identified it its a school or not?

Comment: @DharmeshKheni Thanks, I considered your comment and fixed the issue. Yes, I got the selected object and created an if statement to check the name property if it's has a (school, university, college...) word or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I got is to get the selected place. and then, check the name property. If the name consist of one of the following words, then it's school.
- school
- institute
- college
- university...

Thanks for @DharmeshKheni

Comment: Happy to help you.. :)